# Using javascript to change the value of the text, and the background color of a cell within a table in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to build a staff sign in board using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I know very little at all about JavaScript, and have only previously dabbled in HTML and CSS.

I have 3 columns, one returns the date and time (struggling to get a live timer, but this is a problem for another day)when the button in the next column is pressed, the next column contains the button with the staff members name, which when they click the button, the cell in the next column changes from "Out" to "In" and back.

I am now trying to change the background colour of the third column, depending on the values of the text. I have tried a few different methods, and nothing changes colour. Am I being prevented due to too many scripts running off the same button?

Code example is:

```js
var d = new Date()

function show(id) {
  if (id == 1) {
    document.getElementById('Staff member').value = d;
  }
}

function SM1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SM1");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Out") {
    x.innerHTML = "In";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Out";
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="overflow:scroll; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:150%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:18%;">Time</th>
      <th style="width:58%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:18%;">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:18%;"><input type="text" id="Staff member" value="" style="width:98%; font-size:100%;"></input>
      </td>
      <td style="width:58%;"><button id="1" style="width:100%; font-size:100%;" type="button" onclick="show(this.id);SM1()">Staff member</button></td>
      <td style="width:18%;">
        <div id="SM1">Out</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </body>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Start by correcting that. Then, remove all the inline styling and move it over to CSS classes. After that, remove the inline HTML event attributes and separate your JavaScript from your HTML. In the JavaScript, use `.addEventListener()` to set up your events. In short, lose all the bad habits first. Then, your code will be much cleaner and easier to understand and correct.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen Please do not ever change OP's original code to correct errors they have. Errors in the OPs code could very well be why it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed the indentation of your code and found two syntax errors in your HTML. Nobody can read the code that's squeezed together like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this inside the if/else statement of your SM1 function. Then you can change the color to whichever you like.

```js
var d = new Date()   
function show(id) { 
    if (id == 1) { 
        document.getElementById('Staff member').value = d; 
    } 
}

function SM1() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("SM1"); 
    if (x.innerHTML === "Out") { 
        x.innerHTML = "In";
        x.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }    
    else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Out";
        x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
}
```

```html
<table style="overflow:scroll; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:150%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:18%;">Time</th>
            <th style="width:58%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:18%;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:18%;"><input type="text" id="Staff member" value=""
                    style="width:98%; font-size:100%;"></input></td>
            <td style="width:58%;"><button id="1" style="width:100%; font-size:100%;" type="button"
                    onclick="show(this.id);SM1()">Staff member</button></td>
            <td style="width:18%;">
                <div id="SM1">Out</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </body>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your answer loses its meaning. You can create executable code snippets right here in your answer as I've done via my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ScottMarcus! I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Also worth noting for any other newbies, I had tried .style.backgroundColor both before and after the x.innerHTML segments. The part that I have obviously missed is the x.

Thank you Paolo!

Comment: You're very much welcome. Happy coding, you can actually improve your code just like what Scott said by using .addEventListener() to set up your events.

Comment: Maybe one day, I've still got a lot to learn before I get to a point whereI could implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x.style.backgroundColor`

```js
var d = new Date();
function show(id) {
  if(id == 1) {
    document.getElementById('Staff member').value=d;
  }
}
function SM1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SM1");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Out") {
    x.innerHTML = "In";
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#009900";
  }
  else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Out";
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6666";
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="overflow:scroll; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:150%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:18%;">Time</th>
      <th style="width:58%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:18%;">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:18%;">
        <input type="text" id="Staff member" value="" style="width:98%; font-size:100%;">
      </td>
      <td style="width:58%;">
        <button id="1" style="width:100%; font-size:100%;" type="button" onclick="show(this.id);SM1()">Staff member</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:18%;">
        <div id="SM1">Out</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-color property.

```
function SM1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SM1");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Out") {
    x.innerHTML = "In";
    x.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #BBBB;")
  } else {
   x.innerHTML = "Out";
  }
}
```